# python replace match in string with the same value matched

Tags: python, json, regex

I have a string that is not legal to use for json.dump() and I need to edit it. I need to replace the numbers into the string from `0:` to `"0:"` for esxample. Same for `1` and the other numbers that follow.

This string changes from time to time and the numbers can change as well

```
{"aclList": {0: {"sequence": {1: {"counterData": …etc etc
```

Must become:

```
    {"aclList": {"0": {"sequence": {"1": {"counterData": …etc etc
```

I believe I need to find `\d:` and replace the match with himself plus the qoutes `""`

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?
What doesn't work with your code and where is it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it like that:

```
s = '{"aclList": {0: {"sequence": {1: {"counterData": …etc etc'
for x in re.findall('\d', s):
    s = s.replace(x, f'"{x}"')
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! Very close though: I need to replace `0:` with `"0":` . The columns are not included into the quotes. With your replace they are. And I i use just `\d` is going to replace other digits into the string where they should not

Comment: `'"{x[:-1]}":'` did the trick

Comment: This doesn't work for 2 digit numbers.

Answer (score 1):

This should solve 99% of your problem:

```
(?<={)(\d+)(?=:)
```

https://regex101.com/r/96ReYn/1/ (see https://regex101.com/r/96ReYn/1/codegen?language=python for code)

- `(?<={)` - make sure the previous char is a open curly brace
- `(\d+)` - grab all digits
- `(?=:)` - make sure the next char is a colon

The 1% it will fail against is for data such as [`"I'm going to mess {3: up your day"`](https://regex101.com/r/96ReYn/2) so hopefully it doesn't exist in your "JSON".